# advises (red markers) by STS(eclipse) what do they mean

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

im following an example go spring mvc + hibernate, but i have come with a lot of problems and right now i have something that looks like an error but i dont know.
Im using STS and the spring MVC project template.

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!--  Defines database lookup trough JNDI  --> 
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/paidos" resource-ref="true" />

    <!-- Hibernate configuration -->
    <util:properties id="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        </beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
    </util:properties>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
        p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties" >
            <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.carloscortina.paidosTest.domain" />
        </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.carloscortina.paidosTest.dao.hbn"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.carlosocortina.paidosTest.service" /> 

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.carloscortina.paidosTest" />

    <!-- Controlador para redirigir en caso de existo PersonalRegistration -->
    <view-controller 
        path="personal/RegistrySubmit" 
        view-name="personal/RegistrySubmit" />

</beans:beans>
```

at

```
<tx:annotation-driven> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.carloscortina.paidosTest" />
```

i get this red markes at the line number :

```
advises com.carloscortina.paidosTest.service.PersonalServiceImp.registerPersonal(Personal, 
 Errors)

advised by 
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation)
```

i dont know if this is causing the next error:

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personalController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.carloscortina.paidosTest.service.PersonalService com.carloscortina.paidosTest.PersonalController.personalService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.carloscortina.paidosTest.service.PersonalService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3926)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

PersonalService.java

```
package com.carloscortina.paidosTest.service;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;

import com.carloscortina.paidosTest.domain.Personal;

public interface PersonalService {
    boolean registerPersonal(Personal staff,Errors errors);
}
```

PersonalServiceImpl.java

```
package com.carloscortina.paidosTest.service;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;

import com.carloscortina.paidosTest.dao.PersonalDao;
import com.carloscortina.paidosTest.domain.Personal;;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class PersonalServiceImp {
    @Inject private PersonalDao personalDao;

    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public boolean registerPersonal(Personal staff,Errors errors){
        boolean valid = !errors.hasErrors();
        if(valid){ personalDao.create(staff);}
        return valid;
    }
}
```

i got a marker here too at the line define the method

```
advised by 
 org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation)
```

PersonalController.java

```
package com.carloscortina.paidosTest;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.carloscortina.paidosTest.domain.Personal;
import com.carloscortina.paidosTest.model.PersonalRegistryForm;
import com.carloscortina.paidosTest.service.PersonalService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/personal")
public class PersonalController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonalController.class);
    private final static String regForm="personal/RegistryForm";
    private final static String regSubmit="redirect:RegistrySubmit"; 
    @Inject private PersonalService personalService;

    @RequestMapping(value="new",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPersonalRegistrationForm(Model model){
        logger.info("desplegando forma");
        PersonalRegistryForm form = new PersonalRegistryForm() ;
        model.addAttribute("personalRegForm",form);
        return regForm;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitPersonalRegistrationForm(@ModelAttribute("personalRegForm") @Valid PersonalRegistryForm form,
                BindingResult result){

        convertPasswordError(result);
        personalService.registerPersonal(toPersonal(form), result);
        return (result.hasErrors() ? regForm: regSubmit);
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
        binder.setAllowedFields(new String[]{
            "username","password","confirmPassword","pNombre",
            "sNombre","apellidoP","apellidoM","email","telefono",
            "telCel","categoria","acceptTerms"});
    }

    private static void convertPasswordError(BindingResult result){
        for(ObjectError error: result.getAllErrors()){
            String msg = error.getDefaultMessage();
            if("personal.password.mismatch.message".equals(msg)){
                if(!result.hasFieldErrors("password")){
                    result.rejectValue("password", "error.mismatch");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static Personal toPersonal(PersonalRegistryForm form){
        Personal staff = new Personal();
        staff.setpNombre(form.getpNombre());
        staff.setsNombre(form.getsNombre());
        staff.setApellidoP(form.getApellidoP());
        staff.setApellidoM(form.getApellidoM());
        staff.setTelefono(form.getTelefono());
        staff.setTelCel(form.getTelCel());
        staff.setCategoria(form.getCategoria());

        return staff;
    }
}
```

i dont know if this is enough information.
i hope someone can advise me, thanks int advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking around Google and getting worried about this freaking little red arrow, I have come to know that its just a note from the IDE.

Those little marks are to signal lines that are referring to transactional elements. or are related to `@Transactional` elements.